# Go Link thru iFrame

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe, onclick

I have problem and I tried click link then it doesn't work to open link using target: name of iFrame. i dont want use **href** because im going make show/hide div.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//
function godirect(url, targetname)
{
document.getElementById(targetname).src = url;
//frame[targetname].location.href = url;
}
//-->
</script>
```

in HTML and PHP:

```
$a=0;

echo '<a href="#" onclick="godirect("http://www.google.com", iframe_url'.$a.');">Click Me!</a>';

echo '<iframe class="iframe_url" id="iframe_url'.$a.'"></iframe>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **quote** strings in JavaScript. You are trying to get the id of the element by passing in a variable which you haven't defined.

You are also using the same quote characters to delimit your HTML attribute value as you are using to delimit your JS strings.

To use the approach you are using, while making the minimum number of fixes to make it work:

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="godirect(&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;, &quot;iframe_url'.$a.'&quot;);">Click Me!</a>';
```

Using JS for this is a very silly idea in the first place though, and your implementation fails to have any kind of fallback for when JS is not available (which is odd, since you are taking steps to stop browsers which don't recognise the script element from [rendering the JS as content text](http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/)).

You can do this with plain HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" 
   target="iframe_url<?php echo htmlspecialchars($a); ?>">
   Click Me!
</a>
```

> i dont want use href because im going make show/hide div.

You can do that as well as having a normal, functioning link. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/).

Comment: thanks, David about "&quot;" i didnt know it need that. i thought i can get like this ' " '

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function godirect(url, targetname) {
  window.frames[targetname].location = url;
  //OR 
  //window.open(url,targetname);
  return false;
}
</script>

<?PHP 
$a=0;
?>
<a href="#" onclick="return godirect('http://www.google.com', 'iframe_url<? echo $a; ?>');">Click Me!</a>
<iframe class="iframe_url" name="iframe_url<? echo $a; ?>" id="iframe_url<? echo $a; ?>"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
echo '<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"godirect(\"http:\/\/www.google.com\", iframe_url'.$a.');\">Click Me!</a>';
echo '<iframe class=\"iframe_url\" id=\"iframe_url'.$a.'\"></iframe>';
```

Comment: There is a lot of completely unnecessary escaping of double quote characters there (since the string is delimited with `'` characters, they are the only kind of quote that needs to be escaped for PHP). It makes things very hard to read … and it doesn't fix the problem anyway.